# with adder default blocks exercise. How Do I vary output depending if I get a block to my method or not?

Tags: ruby, closures, block, default, yield

**Here is the rspec I need to pass:**

```
describe "adder" do
   it "adds one to the value returned by the default block" do
 adder do
  5
  end.should == 6
end

it "adds 3 to the value returned by the default block" do
  adder(3) do
    5
  end.should == 8
 end
end
```

**This is my code**

```
def adder(&block)

if block.call == 5
  block.call + 1

else

block.call + 3

end

end
```

**My error output**

adder
    adds one to the value returned by the default block
    adds 3 to the value returned by the default block (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

1) some silly block functions adder adds 3 to the value returned by the default block
     Failure/Error: adder(3) do
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./05_silly_blocks/silly_blocks.rb:5:in `adder'
     # ./05_silly_blocks/silly_blocks_spec.rb:37:in`block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 1):

You pass `adder` an unexpected parameter:

```
adder(3) do
  5
end
```

When `adder` is defined to receive no parameters at all:

```
def adder(&block)
```

You should add an optional parameter to `adder` definition

```
def adder(num=1, &block)
  block.call + num
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This was definitely the missing key! I was getting the order of the num=1 and & block mixed up as well. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
def adder(num = 1)
  yield + num
end
```